# Unable to find Business on Places API

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

We are facing issues in Places API, where we have business and are unable to find them in places API Listing. We had this issue more them 3 times. Even the business has reviews.

### Example

[Here](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enCA766CA766&ei=OxIuWoLuCJq4jAP3u5sQ&q=muscle%20men%20movers%20utah&oq=muscle%20men%20movers%20utah&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.1803.2359.0.2482.5.5.0.0.0.0.85.337.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.337....0.HTc3J7cKv80) is the link for the business in Google Search listing, and [here](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Muscle+Men+Movers/@41.21464,-111.962687,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb28a5e1c9275754c!8m2!3d41.21464!4d-111.962687) is the link on Google's map.

Comment: Please show us the HTTP request that you tried. The following requests works for me and return this place: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Muscle%20Men%20Movers&region=US&key=MY_API_KEY`

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Muscle%20Men%20%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BMovers&key=MY_API_KEY

Comment: I am using autocomplete endpoint but you are using text search endpoint what's the difference and above is the link the i was using, Interestingly it is showing the place now but before today it wasnt showing this business in listing @xomena

Comment: Did you create or edit the business recently in Google My Business? This might be the reason, the place autocomplete database is updated weekly I believe.

Comment: I have to check that with my client. if that the case with autocomplete. Is it same with the endpoint you shared? or every places API endpoint will take around 1 week to show in listing?